# VM migration from on-prem into an Azure Availability Set?

Tags: azure, virtual-machines

As the title asks; is it possible to migrate an on-prem Windows VM, hosted in an HA hypervisor cluster, into an equivalent Azure HA architecture ?

Over several months I have migrated dozens of Windows VM's from on-prem to Azure, both via the classic method (OVF & MVMC) and the more recently preferred Azure Site Recovery feature.
However; I have not noticed any options to migrate a VM into Azure deployed with fault domains as an Availability Set.
I'm aware that one cannot change a VM instance to a set once it's already deployed and I'm likewise aware that the Site Recovery utility is, in itself, a form of cold HA (more accurately DR) via replication which implies that an Availbility Set is moot within the Site Recovery context.

I am looking to the community to verify my statements or enlighten me on possible methods or workarounds to migrate an on-prem VM to an Azure Availability Set and, if indeed possible, what OS restrictions might apply (Win 2016 only?)

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to specify an Availability Set configuration when you configure replication.

See here:

[View and manage VM properties](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/site-recovery/vmware-azure-enable-replication#view-and-manage-vm-properties)

An Availability Set is simply an instruction to Azure to distribute members of a set on to different physical hardware (fault domain) and operational maintenance groups (update domain). So if you have a set of VMs providing the same service the chances of interruption to all VMs in a set is minimised. A web farm or database cluster are both good examples.

As such there are no specific restrictions on what operating systems are supported, as it is more about VM placement.

It wasn't clear in your question what hypervisor or HA technology is in use, but if you are referring to for example VMware HA - whereby a single VM has its state maintained on two hosts simultaneously for failover - that feature is not available today on Azure.  You could partially emulate it with ASR Azure to Azure replication to a degree, but that is more off site failover than making a VM resilient in situ.